How to achieve 8-day average processing of Sentinel-1 data
After preprocessing the Sentinel-1 data within the expected date, I hope to calculate the version of Sentinel-1 data aligned with the MODIS data on the 8th in a certain area(in geemap).Since the complete code is a loop version, I only selected the first time series (2015-02-10~2015-02-17) to display the operation:
import math
import wrapper as wp
# sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD') \
#     .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH')) \
#     .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV')) \
#     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW')) \
#     .filterBounds(roi) \
#     .filterDate(date)

#Parameters
parameter = {  'START_DATE': '2015-02-10',
            'STOP_DATE': '2021-12-31',        
            'POLARIZATION': 'VVVH',
            'ORBIT' : 'BOTH',
            'ROI': ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-130, 30, -100, 50]),# 裁剪要用Rectangle，用Polygon不知道为什么会报错
            'APPLY_BORDER_NOISE_CORRECTION': False,
            'APPLY_SPECKLE_FILTERING': True,
            'SPECKLE_FILTER_FRAMEWORK':'MULTI',
            'SPECKLE_FILTER': 'REFINED LEE',
            'SPECKLE_FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE': 9,
            'SPECKLE_FILTER_NR_OF_IMAGES':10,
            'APPLY_TERRAIN_FLATTENING': True,
            'DEM': ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003'),
            'TERRAIN_FLATTENING_MODEL': 'VOLUME',
            'TERRAIN_FLATTENING_ADDITIONAL_LAYOVER_SHADOW_BUFFER':0,
            'FORMAT': 'LINEAR',
            'CLIP_TO_ROI': True,
            'SAVE_ASSET': False,
            'ASSET_ID': "users/amullissa"
            }
#processed s1 collection
s1_processed = wp.s1_preproc(parameter)
filtered_s1 = s1_processed.filterDate("2015-02-10", "2015-02-17")

backscatter_mean = ee.Image.cat([
        filtered_s1.select('VV').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()),
        filtered_s1.select('VH').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
    ]).set({
        "StartDate": start_date,
        "EndDate": date1,
        "system:time_start": ee.Date(start_date).millis()
    })


If I print the variable backscatter_mean directly here, it will display: User memory limit exceeded.. Can someone tell me how to average the images over an 8-day period?
